# How can I build Visual Studio 2019 projects on Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci, visual-studio-2019

Travis CI recently added a [Windows OS](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/windows/) option to its build system.  Unfortunately, the [preinstalled packages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/windows/#pre-installed-chocolatey-packages) only include Visual Studio 2017.

How can I build Visual Studio 2019 projects (such as .Net Core 3.1 and v142 build tools projects) on Travis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key to using updated build tools is [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), the Windows package manager.  As long as the toolset is available on Chocolatey, you can install it on your Travis VM.

For .Net Core, that means installing the [**dotnetcore-sdk**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore-sdk) package.

For VC++ build tools, there is the [**visualstudio2019buildtools**](https://chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2019buildtools) package, but note you will have to opt in to the *Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64* feature. See below for syntax. A full list of features is available in the [Build Tools component directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2019).

Here's a full `.travis.yml` file for a VS 2019 solution containing a C++ project, a .Net Standard 2.0 project and a .Net Core 3.1 project. The test project makes use of the unmanaged DLL.

```
os: windows
language: cpp
env:
  - MSBUILD_PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin"
install:
  - choco install visualstudio2019buildtools --package-parameters "--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64"
  - choco install dotnetcore-sdk
  - dotnet restore
script:
  - export PATH=$MSBUILD_PATH:$PATH
  - MSBuild.exe -p:Configuration=Release -p:Platform=x64 CppProject/CppProject.vcxproj
  - dotnet build --configuration Release
  - dotnet test DotNetProject.Tests/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/DotNetProject.Tests.dll
```

Comment: Thanks!  Note that this the build script is run in bash, not a Windows shell. (maybe the git bash shell?).  So use forward slashes for directories, quote or escape backslashes, bash environment variables are available but not Windows variables, etc.